# Slider and swich in .net Maui - binding and properties don't work

Tags: data-binding, properties, slider, maui

I am creating phone app in .Net Maui and I have problem with data binding/properties.

Link to git : https://github.com/wojblaz/Clicer-Game---final

This part of my app is for choosing level you will play on. On swich you choose time or points. If you choose time timer will be set on some value and you will have to click as many buttons as you can(points startion from 0) and if you choose points you have to click given amount of times as fast as posible. The value of time/points you will choose from slider - values 5,10,15.

Problems
When I am debbuging method OnSliderValueChanged is never used.

I have also no idea how to make transition - the closer you are to number 5 the bigger the font of lable 5 and lower of 10.

There is also second problem with swich. I want lables to change text based on what is turned on on swich. For example it is time - I want lable time to be set on  based of what is set in slider and lable points to 0 and vice versa points 15 and time 0.

This is code in xaml.

```
    <Switch 
        x:Name="ModeSelector"
        IsEnabled="{Binding BindingContext.SwichTimeCommmand, Source={x:Reference ModeSelector}}"
        IsToggled="{Binding BindingContext.SwichPointsCommmand, Source={x:Reference ModeSelector}}"
        OnColor="LightBlue"
        ThumbColor="Blue"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    <Label Text="{Binding lTime}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="1"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           FontSize="25"/>

    <Label Text="{Binding lPoints}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="2"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"/>


    <Slider x:Name="ValueSelector"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Minimum="5"
        Maximum="15"
        Value="{Binding BindingContext.OnSliderValueChangedCommmand, Source={x:Reference ValueSelector}}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
        [RelayCommand]
        public void SwichTime()
        {
            time = SelectedGameValue;
            lTime = SelectedGameValue.ToString();

            lPoints = "0";
            points = 0;

        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void SwichPoints()
        {
            points = SelectedGameValue;
            lPoints = SelectedGameValue.ToString();

            lTime = "0";
            time = 0;
        }


        [RelayCommand]
        public void OnSliderValueChanged(ValueChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            double value = args.NewValue;

            if (value <=7.5)
            {
                SelectedGameValue = 5;
            }
            else if(7.5 <= value && value <= 12.5)
            {
                SelectedGameValue = 10;
            }
            else if(12.5 <= value)
            {
                SelectedGameValue = 15;
            }

        }
```

**Code after answer. Still there is no text displayed on lables and methods are not executed**

Is there way to do all methods in View Model instead of in cs? And why
there is no references to methods?

As always I updated git.

Xaml

```
                    <Switch
            x:Name="ModeSelector"
            IsToggled="False"
            Toggled="ModeSelector_Toggled"
            OnColor="LightBlue"
            ThumbColor="Blue"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding timeLabel}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               FontSize="25"
               FontFamily="FAR"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding pointsLabel}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="2"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               FontSize="25"/>

       <Slider x:Name="ValueSelector"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Minimum="5"
            Maximum="15"
            ValueChanged="OnSliderValueChanged"/>
```

Xaml.cs

```
using Clicer_Game.ViewModels;
using System.Globalization;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace Clicer_Game.Views;

public partial class ClassicMode : ContentPage
{
    ClassicModelViewModel vm;
    public ClassicMode()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ClassicModelViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = vm;
    }


    private void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e) // this methods will be triggered when the value of slider changes, for example, drag the slider 
    {
        double value = e.NewValue;

        if (value <= 7.5)
        {
            vm.SelectedGameValue = 5;
        }
        else if (7.5 <= value && value <= 12.5)
        {
            vm.SelectedGameValue = 10;
        }
        else if (12.5 <= value)
        {
            vm.SelectedGameValue = 15;
        }

        //And here you can set the text of your timeLabel and your pointLabel based on the switcher ( if IsTime is true which means OnTime, else means OnPoint), 'IsTime' property will be mentioned later
        if (vm.IsTime)
        {
            vm.timeLabel = vm.SelectedGameValue.ToString();
            vm.pointsLabel = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            vm.pointsLabel = vm.SelectedGameValue.ToString();
            vm.timeLabel = "0";
        }

    }

    private void ModeSelector_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ModeSelector.IsToggled)
            {
                vm.IsTime = false;
            }
            else
            {
                vm.IsTime = true;
            }
        }

}
```

ViewModel

```
            public partial class ClassicModelViewModel : ObservableObject
    {


        [ObservableProperty]
        public string timeLabel;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string pointsLabel;

        private int _selectedGameValue;
        private bool _isTime;

        public int SelectedGameValue
        {
            get { return _selectedGameValue; }
            set { _selectedGameValue = value; }
        }

        public bool IsTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _isTime;
            }
            set
            {
                _isTime = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now there is no errors but still code from methods is not executed.  I added link to git if you want you can download code and check it ( of course  everyone can).

Comment: How does the view find its viewmodel? - This is a problem I want to solve.

Comment: Could you now take a look on my answer and check if code is written good and optimally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent hours to solve this problem and I finnaly found answer. Here is my code. But could it be better? Could I use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm?

Xaml:

```
        <Switch
        x:Name="ModeSelector"
        IsToggled="{Binding GameType}"
        OnColor="LightBlue"
        ThumbColor="Blue"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>


    <Label x:Name="TimeLabel"
           Text="{Binding timeLabel}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="1"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           FontSize="20"
           FontFamily="FAR"/>

    <Label Text="{Binding pointsLabel }"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="2"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           FontSize="20"/>

    <Slider x:Name="ValueSelector"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Minimum="5"
        Maximum="15"
        ValueChanged="OnSliderValueChanged"/>
```

Xaml.cs

```
using Clicer_Game.ViewModels;

namespace Clicer_Game.Views;

public partial class ClassicModeView : ContentPage
{
    ClassicModeViewModel vm;

    public ClassicModeView(ClassicModeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = viewModel;
        this.BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
  
        double value = e.NewValue;

    if (value <= 7.5)
    {
        vm.SelectedGameValue = 5;
    }
    else if (7.5 <= value && value <= 12.5)
    {
        vm.SelectedGameValue = 10;
    }
    else if (12.5 <= value)
    {
        vm.SelectedGameValue = 15;
    }

    ((Slider)sender).Value = vm.SelectedGameValue;

}
```

}

```
ViewModel

using System.ComponentModel;
using Clicer_Game.Models;


namespace Clicer_Game.ViewModels
{
    public partial class ClassicModeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ClassicModeModel gameOptions;

        public ClassicModeViewModel()
        {
            LoadGameOptions();
        }
    private void LoadGameOptions()
    {
        gameOptions = new ClassicModeModel(GameType: true, SelectedGameValue: 5, Points: 0, Time: 5, TimeLabel: "0", PointsLabel: "0");
    }       

    public string timeLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return gameOptions.TimeLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != gameOptions.TimeLabel)
            {
                gameOptions.TimeLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(timeLabel));
            }
        }
    }

    public string pointsLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return gameOptions.PointsLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != gameOptions.PointsLabel)
            {
                gameOptions.PointsLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(pointsLabel));
            }
        }
    }

    public int SelectedGameValue
    {
        get { return gameOptions.SelectedGameValue; }
        set 
        {
            gameOptions.SelectedGameValue = value;
            if (GameType)
            {
                timeLabel = SelectedGameValue.ToString();
                pointsLabel = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                pointsLabel = SelectedGameValue.ToString();
                timeLabel = "0";
            }


            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(pointsLabel));
        }
    }

    public bool GameType
    {
        get
        {
            return gameOptions.GameType;
        }
        set
        {
            gameOptions.GameType = value;

            if (value)
            {
                timeLabel = SelectedGameValue.ToString();
                pointsLabel = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                pointsLabel = SelectedGameValue.ToString();
                timeLabel = "0";
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GameType));
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


}
```

}

Model

```
namespace Clicer_Game.Models;


public record ClassicModeModel { 
    public bool GameType;
    public int SelectedGameValue;
    public int Points;
    public int Time;
    public string TimeLabel;
    public string PointsLabel;
    public string Napis;

public ClassicModeModel(bool GameType, int SelectedGameValue, int Points, int Time, string TimeLabel, string PointsLabel)
{
    this.GameType = GameType;
    this.SelectedGameValue = SelectedGameValue;
    this.Points = Points;
    this.Time = Time;
    this.TimeLabel = TimeLabel;
    this.PointsLabel = PointsLabel;
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I make some changes based on your new code. In your ClassicModelViewModel:

```
//INotifyPropertyChanged is notification mechanism that allows the binding infrastructure to be notified when the value of a property changes. 
public partial class ClassicModelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    int time;
    int points;

    public string _timeLabel;
    public string _pointsLabel;
    private int _selectedGameValue;
    private bool _isTime;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string timeLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _timeLabel)
            {
                _timeLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(timeLabel));    
            }
        }
    }

    public string pointsLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return _pointsLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _pointsLabel)
            {
                _pointsLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(pointsLabel));
            }
        }
    }

    public int SelectedGameValue
    {
        get { return _selectedGameValue; }
        set { _selectedGameValue = value; }
    }

    public bool IsTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _isTime;
        }
        set
        {
            _isTime = value;
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

To change font size, you could use a ValueConverter. Just take the '10' label for example. In your ClassicMode.xaml, let the FontSize bind to your slider and use ValueConverter:

```
<Label Text="10"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValueSelector},
               Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource fontSizeChanged}}"  // here i use a converter to convert slider value to font size
    FontFamily="FAS"
    Grid.Column="1"/>
```

also add the following code in your ClassicMode.xaml:

```
<ContentPage 
         ...
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Clicer_Game"
         ...
         >

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:FontSizeChangedConverter x:Key="fontSizeChanged" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

In your FontSizeChangedConverter, you should implement **IValueConverter** Interface. Try the following code:

```
namespace Clicer_Game
{
    public class FontSizeChangedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // just an example here
            int newValue;
            double b = 30 - (Math.Abs((double)value - 10)) * 1;
            newValue = (int)Math.Round(b);
            return newValue.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        { 
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you could refer to [slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/slider), [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/switch), [Data binding basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/data-binding-basics) and [Binding value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters).

I hope my answer could help you.

Comment: Hi. I tried your code (I uptaded question). Without part when i try to change font size there is no errors but methods still are not used. I had to change in cs pointsLabel.Text into vm.pointsLabel because there were errors. Could you also tell me more details how to change font size. I did everything as you suggested but there were so many errors that I decided to do it later.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now the text could be changed when slider's value changed. Please have a try

Comment: I also recommend you to this doc [ViewModels and Property-Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications).

Comment: Could my answer help you, or any other question? We're willing to help

Comment: I menaged to solve problem after some research. I will post my solution in a few hours. If you can please come back and see if my solution it is optimal. Your code helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, with pleasure.